# ListView Items get mixed, when Onclick

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewholder

I'm facing an annoying problem, the values of ListView items get mixed !

I have a simple ListView with a TextView ( with adapter view), and Onclicklistner ImageView, when I click on the ImageView the value of of the textview changes.

But when I scroll up and down, the values get mixed, so it's a little bit annoying.

I have been looking for a solution and I found which named " View Holder " I tried that as well, but i'm having the same problem here is my adapter view code :

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<statisticitem> {

    int likes;

    public adapter(Context context, ArrayList<statisticitem> questionaires) {
        super(context, 0, questionaires);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.button = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final statisticitem s = getItem(position);

        if (s != null) {
            holder.text1.setText(s.getIdQuestion());
            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    likes++;
                    holder.text2.setText("yasser");
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and my view holder class :

```
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    ImageView button;
}
```

Comment: `when I scroll up and down, the values get mixed` please explain what happening

Comment: For example I click on the ImageView of the first item, the value of of textview changes, when I scroll up and down, I found that the textview of other items has changed too

Comment: ok try it as `ViewGroup rowView=(ViewGroup)v.getParent();((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("yasser");` instead of `holder.text2.setText("yasser");`

Comment: Thanks but there is syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Inside the adapter class you are writing a if condition to check 's' is null or not write the else condition also

```
if (s !=null)
   {
       holder.text1.setText(s.getIdQuestion());

       holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                likes++;
            holder.text2.setText("yasser"); 

            }
     });


   }
else
{

//write something to the text view
 holder.text1.setText("");
 holder.text2.setText("");    

}
```

check whether it helps!!!

Comment: is your textview 1 or textview2 getting shuffled..or both?

Comment: Thank you guys ! but always i'm facing the same problem

Comment: If you think that your adapter class is wrong you can take a look at https://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/ which will create a adapter class for you..just supply your .xml to it supply the names    It will create the class gor you. if you have time take a look

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite into

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<statisticitem> {

    int likes;

    public adapter(Context context, ArrayList<statisticitem> questionaires) {
        super(context, 0, questionaires);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        final statisticitem s = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.button = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            if (s != null) {
                holder.text1.setText(s.getIdQuestion());
                holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        likes++;
                        holder.text2.setText("yasser");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder.text1.setText("");
            }
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            if (s != null) {
                holder.text1.setText(s.getIdQuestion());
            } else {
                holder.text1.setText("");
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

You need set `OnClickListener` once at time, because `getView` method execute often then you expected.

And i recommend to you put `likes` into ViewHolder like an

```
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    ImageView button;
    int likes;
}
```

and in `OnClickListener` :

```
holder.likes++;
holder.text2.setText("yasser");
```

instead of

```
likes++;
holder.text2.setText("yasser");
```

Comment: It won't work: You set values only when the view is created. The `if (s != null ... ` part must be right before the `return` sentence.

Comment: @JuanjoVega yes i set once because this is the meaning of ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: @JuanjoVega but you're right i missed check block if convert view exist.

Comment: Thank you guys ! but always i'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I started a project from scratch, added and slightly modified your code, tested... and finally got this:

**statisticitem**

```
public class statisticitem {
    String id;

    public statisticitem(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIdQuestion() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<statisticitem> {
    int[] likes;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<statisticitem> questionaires) {
        super(context, 0, questionaires);

        likes = new int[questionaires.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvText1);
            holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btButton);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvText2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final statisticitem s = getItem(position);

        if (s != null) {
            holder.text1.setText(s.getIdQuestion());
            holder.text2.setText(likes[position] > 0 ? "yasser" : "");

            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    likes[position]++;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        Button button;
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);

        // Build data.
        ArrayList<statisticitem> questionaires = new ArrayList<statisticitem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            questionaires.add(new statisticitem(String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        // Display items.
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, questionaires);
        lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Layouts:**

**activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**itemview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="like" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you guys ! but always i'm facing the same problem